# IndexError: list index out of range in python while listing aws data

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

With my script i am trying to list aws instance id, instance name & volume id but getting the below error " IndexError: list index out of range "

```
import boto3
import csv

def warn(*args, **kwargs):
pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn

#AWS_REGION = "ap-south-1"
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"


ec2_client=boto3.client("ec2", region_name=AWS_REGION)
x=ec2_client.describe_instances()
#print(x)
for pythonins in x['Reservations']:
for printout in pythonins['Instances']:
a=printout['InstanceId']
b=printout["Tags"][0]["Value"]
c=printout["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: ```printout["Tags"]``` or ```printout["BlockDeviceMappings"]``` is probably empty that by calling ```[0]``` on them causes the said error.

Comment: @jobo getting the error for c=printout["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"].

Comment: Try to print the value of printout so we could see its data structure.

Comment: Don't try to index an item that does not exist. You didn't provide an adequate [mre] - how could we possibly provide a solution?